# Critérios em inputs dinamico

Tags: php, ajax

Tenho um input dinâmico que verifica a data em que o usuário seleciona e em seguida retorna as horas disponíveis para agendamento, no entanto quando o usuário selecionar a data do dia `(data = hoje)` eu gostaria que as horas que já passaram fossem excluídas do input.

Exemplo:

A data escolhida é hoje e agora são 16:13, meu input deve exibir

17:00 -
18:00 - 
19:00 -
20:00 -
21:00 -
22:00 -
23:00

Segue o código:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('library.php');
$hoje = date('d/m/Y');
$amanha = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+1),date("Y"))); 
$damanha = date("d/m/Y", mktime(0,0,0,date("m"),(date("d")+2),date("Y")));



$predata = $_POST['predata'];

$sql = "SELECT Hora FROM tbl_agenda WHERE Data = '$predata'";
$atualizahoje = "UPDATE tbl_agenda SET Data='". $hoje ."' WHERE id=33";
$atualizaamanha = "UPDATE tbl_agenda SET Data='". $amanha ."' WHERE id=34";
$atualizadamanha  = "UPDATE tbl_agenda SET Data='". $damanha ."' WHERE id=35";
$qr1 = mysql_query($atualizahoje) or die(mysql_error());
$qr2 = mysql_query($atualizaamanha) or die(mysql_error());
$qr3 = mysql_query($atualizadamanha) or die(mysql_error());
$qr = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$ln1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr1);
$ln2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr2);
$ln3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr3);

$horaatual = date('H:00');

                $horas_hidden = array();
while ($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)) {
    $horas_hidden[] = $ln['Hora'];
}
echo montarOptions($horas_hidden, 23);

function montarOptions($horas_hidden, $total_horas)
{

    $html='<option value="">Selecione..</option>';



    for ($i=0; $i <= $total_horas; $i++) {
        $hora = ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
        $hora .=':00';


        if (in_array($hora, $horas_hidden)) {
          $html.= "<option hidden value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
        } else {
          $html.= "<option value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
        }





   }
   return $html;
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema da seguinte forma:

```
$horaatual = date('H:00');
$horas_hidden = array();
echo $hoje;



while ($ln = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr)) {
    $horas_hidden[] = $ln['Hora'];
}

if ($predata == $hoje) {
echo montarOutro($horas_hidden, 23);
}
else {
echo montarOptions($horas_hidden, 23);
}

function montarOptions($horas_hidden, $total_horas)
{
 $html.='<option value="">Selecione...</option>';





for ($i=0; $i <= $total_horas; $i++) {

    $hora = ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
    $hora .=':00';

    //S¨® deixa passar o restante do c¨®digo se o $i for maior ou igual que a hora atual

    if(strtotime($dataSelecionada.' '.$hora) < strtotime(date('d/m/Y H:i'))) continue;


    if (in_array($hora, $horas_hidden)) {
      $html.= "<option hidden value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
    } else {

        $html.= "<option value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";

    }


}
   return $html;
}



function montarOutro($horas_hidden, $total_horas)
{
 $html.='<option value="">Selecione...</option>';
$dataSelecionada = $predata;

for ($i=0; $i <= $total_horas; $i++) {

    $hora = ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
    $hora .=':00';

    //Só deixa passar o restante do código se o $i for maior ou igual que a hora atual
    if(strtotime($dataSelecionada.' '.$hora) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'))) continue;

    if (in_array($hora, $horas_hidden)) {
      $html.= "<option hidden value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
    } else {
      $html.= "<option value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
    }
}
   return $html;
}                       
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode verificar no seu looping a hora atual.

```
//Captura a data selecionada
$dataSelecionada = '2016-06-30';

for ($i=0; $i <= $total_horas; $i++) {

    $hora = ($i < 10) ? '0'.$i : $i;
    $hora .=':00';

    //Só deixa passar o restante do código se o $i for maior ou igual que a hora atual
    if(strtotime($dataSelecionada.' '.$hora) < strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i'))) continue;

    if (in_array($hora, $horas_hidden)) {
      $html.= "<option hidden value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
    } else {
      $html.= "<option value=\"{$hora}\">{$hora}</option>";
    }
}
```

---

Obs.: As funções mysql_ do php esta deprecated, você deve usar PDO ou mysqli_

Comment: Bom dia, o código funciona porém se a data escolhida for amanhã o campo ainda realiza o filtro tentei resolver aqui com um if mais não consegui `if($predata == $hoje) continue;`, eu preciso que o filtro ocorra somente se a data escolhida for igual a hoje.

Comment: Alterei a resposta, basta você capturar a data atual e no `if` que compara os horários, fazer a comparação da data completa

Comment: Boa tarde, tentei fazer dessa forma porém aparece todas as horas disponíveis mesmo se eu selecionar a data de hoje.

Comment: Você esta alterando a data da variável `$dataSelecionada`?

Comment: Sim, coloquei `$dataSelecionada = $predata`

Comment: O formato dessa `$predata` esta em `Y-m-d` ?

Comment: Não, mais eu fiz a alteração, o meu formato de data é d\m\Y, no seu código fiz a adaptação `strtotime(date('d\m\Y H:i')))`, também fiz o teste colocando o data selecionada manualmente e com o seu formato e obtive o mesmo problema.

Comment: O [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) só aceita formatos de datas em inglês, você deve deixar como esta no código e alterar a sua data para o formato correto